# Is 0 line item and 0 balances add for Quick book desktop

Tags: quickbooks

In Quick book desktop is support 0 balance but does not have any customer associated with it.

Comment: Please elaborate your question !

Comment: Is it valid scenario 1 line item with 0 balances add invoice in QBD